# Polkadot.js api how to get the balance of an account at a particular nonce

Tags: javascript, api, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I am trying to get the balance of a wallet account using the wallet address and it's nonce. For example I can get the latest balance and the total number of nonce of a wallet address with this.

const { nonce, data: balance } = await api.query.system.account(ADDR);
console.log(`balance of account is ${balance.free} and a nonce of ${nonce}`);

I'd like to get the balance of an address at a particular nonce like.

get the balance of account x at nonce number y

Thank you for reading.

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ would be a much better place to surface this question, could you ask there instead? 